# Required. SQL Azure Backup Alerts

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-azure-alerts

SQL Azure backups.
Is there a way to get emails alerts when the backup's are processed?
I have a client that needs this for an ISO accreditation.

Comment: Hi @scottsanpedro, did you found the solution? Currenly I have exactly the same requirements, also for an ISO accreditation

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Azure storage blob events to observe new backup blobs being created. You can filter for your need : full backup, differential backup, transaction log backup.

Now, you can handle the events accordingly using event handlers and send email.

[More information on Azure Storage Blob Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview)

Comment: Thank you @VenkataramanR, I will withdraw my reply

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani, no problem

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look and comment.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Backup Email Alert is not available. We can achieve using

1. You have *SQL in Azure VM* use **Recovery Services Vaults**

Search the **Recovery Service Vault** in *Azure portal*

[image]

Open Recovery Service Vault and Create a new **Recovery Service Vault** and add required details

[image]

Open created Recovery Service vault and select **Backup Alerts**.

[image]

Select **Configure notification**

[image]

Select Email notification **ON** and add **Recipient’s Email** which you want to receive alert and save it.

[image]

After successful configuration you can receive the alert mail.
Please Refer: [Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-monitoring-built-in-monitor#:%7E:text=%20Azure%20Monitor%20alerts%20for%20Azure%20Backup%20%28preview%29,alerts%2C%20you%20must%20create%20an%20action...%20More%20)

2. For alternate solution: Create Alert to Monitor (You have Azure SQL Server Database without VM)

Please Refer: [Click here](https://dataplatformlabs.com/creating-alerts-to-monitor-an-azure-sql-database/)